# Установка DelphiX для Rad Studio 2010

Tags: delphi, embarcadero

Где найти компоненты и мануалы DelphiX на русском?

Answer (score 1):

DelphiX - это набор компонентов для облегчения работы с DirectX. Из гугла:

- [DelphiX](http://www.micrel.cz/Dx/)
- [Туториал](http://www.gamedev.ru/pages/hex/articles/DelphiX)

Comment: Спс конечно, но этот  сайт специально сделали для подобных вопросов. И вдруг, мне ответит кто-то хорошо знакомый с DelphiX, и мануалы другие знает. А тот, что вы мне дали уже недели 2 в закладках у меня лежит)

Comment: +ко всему, пробывал искать, но скачал не то... вот и спросил здесь.

Comment: Но согласитесь, официальный сайт DelphiX ищется на ура ;)

Comment: Я все равно столкнулся с проблемой. После установки компонентов и добавления одного из них на форму, конкретно dxdraw, во время компиляции выдается ошибка в uses: dxdraws не может найти, хотя я ее специально (после первой ошибки) скопировал в места скопления dcu файлов.

Comment: @alextrof94: Вот про это и стоило бы спросить ;)

Answer (score -1):

Вот [оффсайт](http://embarcadero.com/) - с него можно взять DelphiXE в виде 30 дневного триала.

DelphiX в природе нет. Что значит мануалы для нее, не понятно.